# a python import is working from command line, and not working from pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I have a script that imports tensorflow. 
At the beginning of the script is manually set the sys.path, and working directory with:

```
import os; os.chdir('/home/my_project'); print(os.getcwd())
import sys; sys.path = [...]; print(sys.path)
```

When I run the script from PyCharm, I'm getting:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I run it from the linux command line, with the same python interpeter it works. I know I'm using the exact interpeter and script, because I copied the command from Pycharm console. The sys.path, and os.getcwd outputs are the same when running from the cmd, and from the PyCharm.

I'm using cuda-8.0, tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64` add ld library path to path variable

Comment: i print from the script the following values, and I can tell that they are the same when I ran it from Pycharm, and from cmd:
`os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']`
`os.getcwd()`
`sys.path`

Comment: solved: 
I seems that from some reason the settings of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH from the PyCharm environment variables don't really affect it, and setting os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] don't help for the imports if it's set from the script itself. 

What solved the problem was that I ran PyCharm directly from the cmd, so it had the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @Tal Maybe add an answer of your own with the way you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that from some reason the settings of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the PyCharm environment variables don't really affect it, and setting `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']` don't help for the imports if it's set from the script itself. What solved the problem was that I ran PyCharm directly from the cmd, so it had the same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`